# why is the pump in EDFA amplifier used?

Tags: amplifier

due to attenuation the signal has loss in power, but not frequency, so why here in EDFA optical amplifier use the pump since the amplification medium ist the Eribium ?
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The pump laser provides power for the amplifier.  Without power the amplifier cannot amplify.  The pump laser is of a shorter wavelength than the signal, which provides the energy for stimulated emission in the amplifier.

See: https://www.rp-photonics.com/erbium_doped_fiber_amplifiers.html

Comment: so it is the same wavelength as the signal ? and why does the pump go in the same fiber as the signal ?

Comment: The pump is a shorter wavelength than the signal, and it does not necessarily go through the same fiber as the signal.  Often it propagates in the cladding of a double clad fiber.